# Android internal storage benchmark giving impossibly fast read speeds

Tags: java, android, io, benchmarking

So I'm creating a benchmarking app for Androids. Right now I'm trying to add in the ability to test the internal storage read/write speed. To test the read speed, I first create a file (a few megabytes). Next, I then read back the file as many times as I can in 5 seconds, then calculate the speed.

Below is example code demonstrating a simplified version of my code. The output I'm getting from the code (on a Galaxy S4) is:

```
File Size (should be 4096kb): 4096kb
Total Read: 3137792 MB
Read Rate: 612.85 MB/sec
```

which is obviously too fast to be real (I would expect it to be somewhere in the 30-60MB range).

Test Code:

```
private void readTest()
{
    final int FILE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
    final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 128;
    final int CHUNK_NUM = FILE_SIZE / CHUNK_SIZE;
    final int READ_DURATION = 5000;

    File outputDir = Globals.getContext().getCacheDir();
    try
    {
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("InternalStorageRead", "tmp", outputDir);

        // Generate some data to write to temp file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK_SIZE; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = (byte)((i % 256) - 128);
        }

        // Write generated data into file
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile));
        for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK_NUM; i++)
        {
            bos.write(buffer);
            bos.flush();
        }
        bos.close();

        System.out.println("File Size (should be " + (FILE_SIZE / 1024) + "kb): " + (tempFile.length() / 1024) + "kb");

        long startTimeMS = System.currentTimeMillis();

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
        long bytesRead = 0;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeMS < READ_DURATION)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int read = is.read(buffer);
                if (read > 0)
                {
                    bytesRead += read;
                }
                else
                {
                    // EOF - start reading again from beginning
                    is.close();
                    is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
                }
            }
        }
        is.close();

        double mb = bytesRead / (1024.0 * 1024.0);
        System.out.println("Total Read: " + (bytesRead / 1024) + " MB");

        double readRate = mb / (READ_DURATION / 1000.0);
        System.out.println("Read Rate: " + readRate + " MB/sec");
    }
    catch (IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

Does there appear to be something I messed up with my code (something I missed, or compiler optimizations), or is it something with Android? Like an memory cache or something of that nature.

Comment: Linux usually runs with a disk cache.  I don't know about Android specifically, but my guess would be that the same is true.

Comment: As in it caches the files in memory? Do you know of any way to bypass it (other than just making a very large file so that it is larger than the cache)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is being cached in RAM, so you are measuring speed from there. You need to open the file for Direct I/O to avoid caching. Then some later Android versions or HW devices do not allow this on the Internal Drive. Also, the path to drives is not standard. See my DriveSpeed section of:

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/android%20benchmarks.htm#anchor17

There you can obtain my DriveSpeed.apk with Internal and External Drive buttons plus an option not to delete a test file. Powering off and on clears the cache and reading can be measured from the drive (once). You can arrange to do that with 3 programs one to write, one to read and one to delete.

There is also DriveSpd2.apk where you enter the path to use.

Eclipse project with Java and  JNI/C codes are in

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/Android%20Benchmarks.zip